# "the user authentication failed!" error while accessing Discovery.svc using CRM 2011 XRM

Tags: iis, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, impersonation, xrm

I am writing a .NET website which is accessing CRM dynamics.

I have setup the website on IIS, and impersonated the CRM user so that the website runs in the context of CRM accessible user.

The same code was working fine when the site was pointing to demo CRM Dynamics portal
I have deployed the site on another server, and now pointing to live CRM dynamics portal, and I got stuck up at "The user authentication failed!" error.
Few things I can confirm is - 1) Impersonated user has access to CRM Dynamics. 2) OrgnaizationName is correct.
The .NET Site is consuming Discovery.svc to access CRM Dynamics

Comment: any resolution/quick fix since then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check the HTTP bindings of the Dynamics CRM website in IIS. I don't remember exactly but just try playing around by disabling HTTP binding, enabling HTTPS and the other way around.

Even better replicate the bindings as you see on the first server where your application was working fine.

In any case let me know the results.

Comment: CRM Dynamics site is deployed at another environment, and is not accessible. I will check with the support engineer over there. were you facing the same issue?

Comment: Yeah I kinda faced a very similar issue and it was ultimately resolved by fixing the bindings.

Comment: I got to see the bindings on CRM website. Currently it has both HTTP (5555) and HTTPS (443) bindings setup. However, HTTPS is something which is exposed as public-facing URL. But I tried disabling HTTP and it didn't work. it is giving the same error message.

Comment: just try doing an IISRESET and also make sure you application uses the same app-pool as your CRM website.

Comment: hmmm .. it has to be with the website bindings. What exactly is your scenario like? Website running on HTTP and CRM on HTTP and HTTPS both? If yes, can you temporarily disable HTTPS from CRM and do IISRESET and app pool refresh. If this fixes, then we should be good but if it doesn't then will need to do some more research.